# HTML - Make table minimum height matches the current screen height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am designing a web page using table, the layout looks like the following:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr><td></td></tr>
      <tr><td></td></tr>
      <tr><td></td></tr>
      </table>
    </body>
  </html>
```

I need my table minimum height to match the screen height, that is when the content height is less than the screen height it should match the screen height by adding space in the middle row.

What is the simplest way to achieve this?

Comment: it isn't good way to design page using tables, better way is using div elements. Look to [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) grid system it is more proper way for creating layouts.

Comment: I know it is better to use div but tables is used and I have to make it using minimum modifications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `<table>` elements for layout. In fact, the CSS3 flexbox specification was created for layout requirements like yours—the trick is to use display flex on the parent element, and ensure that the row you want to fill the minimum height is allowed to grow, using `flex-grow: 1`. The parent should have a minimum height of `100vh`.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
div.content-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
div.row-2 {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #eee;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="row-1">Row 1</div>
  <div class="row-2">Row 2</div>
  <div class="row-3">Row 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is working well by setting the min height of the table, one thing still to accept answer as complete: the extra space is distributed across rows, I need to add extra space just for the row in the middle, thank you

Comment: @ammcom In a rush I misunderstood your question—updated my answer now. My advice is to *not* use `<table>` elements for layout, and use CSS3 flexbox to help you with achieving the layout you want. See updated demo.

Comment: I know using div is better but actually the current layout uses table and setting min-height to 100vh did work for the entire table, I may redesign the page using your solutionn if there is no other thing to do but as the first suggestion of setting min-height of table works it is better if I can add some styles to rows so that I restrict the growth of the height of them.

Comment: @ammcom You might as well start converting now—since it is semantically invalid to begin with to use tables to dictate layout. Table elements have a peculiar behavior in which it automatically attempts to distribute dimensions across rows and columns as it sees fit, and might disregard certain CSS rules.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it.  You could assign a height to the table cells in the first and last rows, and then the middle row would fill up the remaining space.

You need to assign a height to the table, 100vh.  This works better than using 100% (which requires setting a height to the body and html elements, which does not always work in all browsers).

Note that when you specify a height to a table, the height value is treated as a minimum value.  Browsers will expand the table's height as needed to make sure that all the content is displayed.

In the example below, you can see the scrolling effect on the smaller display window.  If you view the demo in full page mode, then the content is positioned without a vertical scroll bar.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}
td {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}
.r1 td, .r3 td {
  height: 50px;
}
.r2 td {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="r1">
    <td>Header</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="r2">
    <td>Content: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur tempus sapien erat, ac hendrerit quam euismod vitae. Morbi sed dolor in quam consequat hendrerit condimentum fringilla arcu. Nulla mollis, neque non tincidunt auctor, libero ex viverra felis, a tempor purus leo eget justo. Aenean mattis est tincidunt ante tincidunt, quis aliquam neque bibendum. Sed id mauris non ligula malesuada porta in nec velit. Aliquam a erat elementum, dapibus dui sed, pulvinar mauris. Duis egestas luctus turpis non feugiat. Mauris sit amet ornare quam. Nunc rutrum orci lacus, vel commodo arcu convallis sed. Donec et urna tellus. Integer pulvinar ante at urna molestie, sit amet euismod turpis venenatis. Etiam congue quis mi in pretium. Aenean commodo ante et odio ultricies, sed sodales nisi tincidunt. Sed convallis tincidunt aliquam. Duis congue magna id congue tincidunt.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="r3">
    <td>Footer</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I tried it but it seems not working, I set the height of html and body to 100%, set the height of the table to 100% and set a fixed height to rows other than the middle one with no luck

Comment: What browser are you using?